# Add line in Excel 2010 if cell is not empty

Tags: excel, line, addition, vba

I am trying to stack the values of a chart into a single column.

So my data looks like this:

```
-------A--------B  
1 Value1 Value2  
2 Value3  
3 Value4  
4 Value5 Value6  
5 Value7
```

If cell 1B does not = 0 I want to add a line between line 1 and 2 (I'll call that line "11") and take Value2 and paste it into 11A
If cell 1B is blank I want it to do nothing

So I want my data to look like this:

```
1....Value1   
11..Value2  
2....Value3  
3....Value4   
4....Value5   
41..Value6   
5....Value7
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The Id it's column "A", value1 column "B", value2 column "C". 
 The code is:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 9999
    If Range("C" & i).Value <> "" Then
        Range("A" & i + 1 & ":C" & i + 1).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("A" & i + 1).Value = Range("A" & i).Value & 1
        Range("B" & i + 1).Value = Range("C" & i).Value
        Range("C" & i).Value = ""
    End If

    If Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then Exit For
Next
```